# Saving CheckBox Items to Database Access

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

i have vb.net application form.
It contains ID, Age,Name as Textbox and TC as Checkbox.
I have following code to these items, but checkbox items is saved automatically whether checked or not.
So what to do?

```
[Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim con_str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Satyam\Documents\Database2.accdb"
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = con_str
        con.Open()
        'MsgBox(con.State)

        Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from Table1", con)
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While myReader.Read()

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AddTable1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddTable1.Click
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = con_str
        con.Open()
        'MsgBox(con.State)

        cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(ID,Age,Name,TC) values ('" & IDtxt.Text & "','" & Agetxt.Text & "','" & Nametxt.Text & "','" & TCtxt.Text & "')", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Added Successfuly")

        Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from Table1", con)
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Agetxt.Clear()

        While myReader.Read()

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid SQL injection.  Concatenating your sql string like that will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. This is for 3 checkboxes. You can extend it for 10 checkboxes.
Have a look here:

```
    Dim hbStr As String
    Dim bgStr As String
    Dim tcStr As String

    If hb.Checked Then
        hbStr = hb.Text
    Else
        hbStr = ""
    End If

    If bg.Checked Then
        bgStr = bg.Text
    Else
        bgStr = ""
    End If

    If tc.Checked Then
        tcStr = tc.Text
    Else
        tcStr = ""
    End If

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Connection String")
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1(ID,Age,Name,TC,HB.BG) values ('" & IDtxt.Text & "','" & Agetxt.Text & "','" & Nametxt.Text & "','" & tcStr & "','" & hbStr & "','" & bgStr & "')"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Just one more thing- would it be possible that if don't select any checkbox then the respective column in db will be empty.

Comment: Ya if you want it to be empty just pass that value this way.
 `cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(ID,Age,Name,TC) values ('" & IDtxt.Text & "','" & Agetxt.Text & "','" & Nametxt.Text & "','')", con) 'Just pass empty string in single quotes` 
Just make sure that field is not `NOT NULL` in database.
Please mark the answer if it helps.:)

Comment: in this case if there are three checkbox as TC,HB,BG- then what will be the code.?

Comment: So you mean the checkbox you selected that value you want to insert? Or you have different fields for each checkbox.

Comment: i have different fields for each checkbox

Comment: i have 10 checkbox and similar column in database.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry it save only TC not Hb.**

```
If Hbtxt.Checked Then
   cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(ID,Age,Hb) values ('" & IDtxt.Text & "','" & Agetxt.Text & "','" & Hbtxt.Text & "')", con)
Else
   cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(ID,Age,Hb,) values ('" & IDtxt.Text & "','" & Agetxt.Text & "','')", con)
End If

If TCtxt.Checked Then
  cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(ID,Age,TC) values ('" & IDtxt.Text & "','" & Agetxt.Text & "','" & TCtxt.Text & "')", con)
Else
  cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into Table1(ID,Age,TC) values ('" & IDtxt.Text & "','" & Agetxt.Text & "','')", con)
End If
```

Comment: I tried this code but i got a query                                                                  the query is - Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Connection String")-Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. (Argumentexception was unhandled)